# Struggling to dynamically create event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

I have a page where users can enter work experience. This is done by adding dynamic forms via Cocoon and Simple Forms.

Every time a new form is added, I run a function to instantiate Magicsuggest on a certain `<input>` in the form:

```
function add_company_autocomplete(element) {
    company_magicsuggest = $(element).magicSuggest({});

    // show or hide the fields on form instantiation
    show_hide_logo_upload(company_magicsuggest, element);

    // show or hide the fields as input value changes
    $(company_magicsuggest).on('selectionchange', function() {
        show_hide_logo_upload(company_magicsuggest, element);
    });
}
```

This function in turn binds an event handler `show_hide_logo_upload()` that looks out for changes to the Magicsuggest field's contents.

My problem is that the event handlers all share a pointer to the same `company_magicsuggest` object. Every time I run the above function, it overwrites `company_magicsuggest` with the new object, and consequently, the event handlers all reference the same object, and are unable to act on different objects as I want them to.

How can I write `add_company_autocomplete()` so that it passes the newly-created Magicsuggest instance to the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but really I feel like it's just sidestepping the problem instead of addressing it.

```
function add_company_autocomplete(element) {
    $($(element).magicSuggest({})).on('selectionchange', function() {
        show_hide_logo_upload(this, element);
    }).trigger('selectionchange');
}
```